# Force connecting to VPN right after connecting to the Internet

Tags: linux, vpn

I use Ubuntu on my trips and from time to time I need to connect to public hotspots using an insecure channel. And I don't want to expose my information to any hijacker sitting nearby... So I usually connect through a VPN right after being connected to the internet.

The problem is that the system apps are usually faster than me clicking the VPN connection, so they start sending lots of data through the insecure channel.

I seek for a way to tell the system "connect to the internet, and if you succeed, block all traffic (except VPN) until the VPN connection is established".

I want to use this in the most "modular" way possible - internet through either eth0 or wlan0, several different VPN connections. I don't mind configuring a bit of stuff before connecting - e.g. to tell which internet and VPN connection to use.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior? Ideally using NetworkManager, because connecting to WiFi over /etc/network/interfaces is probably a bit of pain.

Bonus question: how to make this robust enough to handle the "landing pages" many hotspots show to you before they allow you accessing the internet?

Comment: You probably want https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @lain: I'm specifically asking for ways to configure NetworkManager. It's possible there is some software handling this, but my main concern is really NetworkManager.

Comment: Our concern is that you're asking an end-user / help desk type question on a site where those types of questions are clearly not welcome if you read up on what serverfault is for.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I thought I'm publishing on SU, not SF. That was some mistake. Thanks for the migration then =)